# App launcher bar display after upgrading to ubuntu 21.04 painfully slow

Tags: 21.04

I've noticed the app icons take several minutes or more to display in **Ubuntu 21.04**.  Was instantaneous in **Ubuntu 20.10**.  Each time after I login to **Ubuntu 21.04** clicking **Settings** speeds the population of the launcher bar with icons.  Going through this process once is usually enough.  One suggestion was removing **tlp** (power management of some kind) except I didn't have this installed.  How should one resolve this issue?

Each time after I login a clear but empty ribbon is displayed with nine dots (**Show Applications**), at the bottom, on the left of my screen. I waited at least 5 minutes and no app icons appeared. Bringing up **Settings** eg. Screen Display caused app icons eg. Firefox, Thunderbird Mail, Files, etc. to almost immediately appear. This has to be done every time I login not just the first time. This behaviour started after upgrading from 20.10 to 21.04.  This still occurred May 20th.  All updates applied.  Considering using Gnome 40 but haven't.  Tried `sudo apt-get install gnome-menus --reinstall` and `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell --reinstall` from terminal window followed by a system restart.  No change.

I observed, on another laptop computer, June 6th the 21.04 release upgrade from 20.10 worked without this issue.

Comment: Can you be more clear? With "App launcher", do you mean the dock on the left of the screen? You are telling that it takes several minutes to display after you have logged in?

Comment: Please use "edit" to improve your answer itself. Comments may disappear, and not all will proceed reading the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved] - The problem lies somewhere in Wayland.  I fixed mine by:

1. Power-on/Restart computer.
2. Click on the account you want to log-in to.
3. Click the icon bottom right.
4. Change setting from Ubuntu to "Ubuntu on Xorg"
5. Enter password and log in.

Everything should now show up near instantaneously.